# Tensorflow2 object detection error when i am creating train.record and test.record

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection

usage: generate_tfrecord.py [-h] [-i IMAGEDIR] [-o OUTPUTDIR] [-r RATIO] [-x]
generate_tfrecord.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /content/training_demo/images/train -l /content/training_demo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt
usage: generate_tfrecord.py [-h] [-i IMAGEDIR] [-o OUTPUTDIR] [-r RATIO] [-x]
generate_tfrecord.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /content/training_demo/images/test -l /content/training_demo/annotations/label_map.pbtxt

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue but after I opened the `generate_tfrecord.py` file directly on notebook and paste the same code to it then it recompiled successfully.